# c# custom icmp echo reply

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, icmp

I need to send reply with my custom message to a client on response to the client's echo request message. Code of my server:

```
IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(args[0]);
IPEndPoint ipMyEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 0);
EndPoint myEndPoint = (ipMyEndPoint);
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Icmp);
socket.Bind(myEndPoint);
socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, BitConverter.GetBytes(1), null);
while (true)
{
    Byte[] ReceiveBuffer = new Byte[socket.ReceiveBufferSize];
    var nBytes = socket.ReceiveFrom(ReceiveBuffer, ReceiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref myEndPoint);
    var icmpType = ReceiveBuffer[ICMP_TYPE_OFFSET];
    if (icmpType == ICMP_TYPE_ECHO_REQUEST)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Echo Request received from " + myEndPoint);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0} bytes", nBytes);
        if (nBytes > PAYLOAD_OFFSET)
        {
            var payLoadSize = nBytes - PAYLOAD_OFFSET;
            byte[] payLoad = new byte[payLoadSize];
            Array.Copy(ReceiveBuffer, PAYLOAD_OFFSET, payLoad, 0, payLoadSize);
            string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(payLoad);
            Console.WriteLine("Data hex: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(payLoad));
            Console.WriteLine("Data text: {0}", msg);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("---------------");
        //IPEndPoint ip = myEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
        //Console.WriteLine("Sending request to remote " + ip.Address);
        //byte[] payload = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("nice job, man!");
        //socket.SendTo(BuildIcmpMessage(payload, payload.Length), myEndPoint);
        //break;
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions();

        options.DontFragment = true;
        string data = "Nice job, man";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        int timeout = 120;
        IPEndPoint ip = myEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
        Console.WriteLine("Sending request to remote " + ip.Address);
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(ip.Address, timeout, buffer, options);
        Console.WriteLine(reply.Status);
        break;

    }
}
```

I tried both commented and uncommented snippets of the code to send my custom response, however nothing of these reached the client (according to wireshark logs from client's machine). The only thing which has reached the client is automatically generated (by .NET socket or something like this) echo reply which has the same payload part as original request. I saw one similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019053/sending-back-custom-icmp-echo-response) here, but there wasn't an answer on the question.
If I use Ping class to send response (actually just new ping) then it is failed with Time-out reply status. If I use `socket.SendTo` then nothing is reached the client.
So how can I send my custom reply to client's icmp echo request?

Comment: "_The only thing which has reached the client is automatically generated (by .NET socket or something like this) echo reply which has the same payload part as original request._" ICMP is an integral part of IP, so it is IP using ICMP to reply to the echo request. That is below your application on the network stack, meaning that IP has already responded before you can see the request.

Comment: Hint: Run it with a debugger and set a breakpoint inside where you think you got a message. Does the breakpoint ever trigger?

Comment: @Steve do you mean client machine? Client machine, according to wireshark, receives only one echo reply packet from server's ip. If I run wireshark on the server, then I see that it tries to sends my custom replies to the client, but client doesn't receive them